# I try to use selenium to search on google trends

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-trends

I try to use selenium to search on google trends. After a few times I got "You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later." How to fix it?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 ')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
team = 'new york'
date='now%201-d'
url='https://www.google.ie/trends/explore#q='+team+'&date='+date
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: seems you get legitimate error. What is there to fix?

Comment: The error message gives you the solution. What else should we suggest? Maybe not to run automated test on third party sites.

Comment: use sendkeys and not direct url request

Comment: @LeonBarkan i did in my project as you say, and it did work! thanks a million

Comment: @卢少烽 you welcome, glad to help.

Comment: If this question is no longer needed, please delete it or post an answer and accept it.